Was there ever a nonstick RevereWare copper-bottom pot?
I’ve come into possession of a (in poor condition) Revere Ware copper-bottom steel pot and am trying to figure out something puzzling about it. According to the person I got it from, it originally had a nonstick coating. However, the closest to “nonstick” that I can see referring to this type of pot is anodized aluminum, rather than more modern Teflon/etc coatings.
Did they ever make a copper-bottomed steel pot with a nonstick coating other than anodized aluminum?

It seems they made some pans with a teflon coating, including some copper-bottomed ones. I found this site, which states:

The “Perma-Loc” surface required a two-step process – first a metal/ceramic substrate was applied, followed by the teflon coating. Various coatings were used (Teflon®, Teflon II®, Ironstone®) but all carried the “Perma-Loc” name (Revere advertised this coating as “Locked-On” or “twice applied Teflon®”. Perma-Loc was offered on Deluxe Revere Ware, Neptune, Copper Clad Revere Ware, and all the aluminum lines


Deluxe Revere Ware (9000 line) was brought out in 1962 using the traditional copper clad SS construction and profiles, while adding a sleek new handle design with slide-out hanging loops and low slung “pagoda” styled lids with inverted conical knobs. Responding to consumer demand for a non-stick cooking surface,
Deluxe Revere Ware was initially produced with a highly polished “Perma-Sheen” interior surface but Revere subsequently discontinued all use of “Perma-Sheen”, offering the “Perma-Loc” Teflon® surface in its place.

So it seems there definitely were some product lines that had the copper bottom/cladding and a Teflon coating.
